# AVPlayer playback with Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, playback

I'm having issues with playing back a video. All I want is for the video to playback after the launch image has been displayed. I followed this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYATp9--VIM)  tutorial but when I simulated I received a blank screen.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var videoView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.setupView()  
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func setupView() {
        let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("streetview", ofType: "mov")!)

        let player = AVPlayer(URL:path)

        let newLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        newLayer.frame = self.videoView.frame
        self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
        newLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

        player.play()
    }
}
```

Please help me if you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just getting a blank black screen, it would generally point to an issue with the source of the video. I'd check that you're spelling the name of your file correctly and that it definitely is a .mov file.

I use this code to launch the `AVPlayer` and play my video. It plays a video from a URL from the internet. I have it inside my button function so it happens when the user presses the play button I have:

```
let videoURL = NSURL(string: "YOUR URL") {
let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player
self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {

    playerViewController.player!.play()

}
```

I can confirm this works for me in Swift 2.0

Comment: Thank you, the issue was with the file itself and not the codes. I just changed it to an mp4 file instead and it worked

Comment: @Chace Good to hear! If my answer helped feel free to mark it correct :)